# How to remove old ipykernels

Tags: bash, ubuntu, kernel

I'm messing around with linux and trying to use environments. During this experimentation period I created various kernels that serve no purpose.

```
source my_environment_name/bin/activate  
python -m pip install ipykernel          
python -m ipykernel install

python -m ipykernel install --user --name=test_venv
```

I'm trying to delete old kernels, but I don't know where they are stored and I can't work out how to do it using terminal. I naively tried:

```
python -m ipykernel uninstall --user --name=test_venv
```

But it doesn't work. How do I clean up my environment by removing old kernels?

Answer (score 2):

Found 'em:

```
/home/solebay/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/env
```

Comment: For Windows, it was at `C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels`

Answer (score 1):

Use `jupyter kernelspec` command to manage your kernels:

```bash
$ jupyter kernelspec --help
Manage Jupyter kernel specifications.

Subcommands
-----------

Subcommands are launched as `jupyter kernelspec cmd [args]`. For information on
using subcommand 'cmd', do: `jupyter kernelspec cmd -h`.

list
    List installed kernel specifications.
install
    Install a kernel specification directory.
uninstall
    Alias for remove
remove
    Remove one or more Jupyter kernelspecs by name.
install-self
    [DEPRECATED] Install the IPython kernel spec directory for this Python.
provisioners
    List available provisioners for use in kernel specifications.

To see all available configurables, use `--help-all`
```

```bash
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  ch701      /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/ch701
  isis       /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/isis
  python3    /opt/conda/envs/isis/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

```bash
$ jupyter kernelspec remove ch701
Kernel specs to remove:
  ch701                 /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/ch701
Remove 1 kernel specs [y/N]: y
[RemoveKernelSpec] Removed /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/ch701
```

```bash
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  isis       /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/isis
  python3    /opt/conda/envs/isis/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

Voilà!